# google drive spreadsheet error reading worksheet

Tags: c#, google-sheets, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I try to read a specific worksheet from a spreadsheet.
Including 5 worksheets and 4 of them I have no problem with, but the one I want to read gives this error:

> Exception:Thrown: "Parsing failed"
>   (Google.GData.Client.ClientFeedException) A
>   Google.GData.Client.ClientFeedException was thrown: "Parsing failed"

code:

```
            SpreadsheetQuery query = new SpreadsheetQuery();
            SpreadsheetFeed feed = myService.Query(query);

            var campaign = (from x in feed.Entries where x.Title.Text.Contains("my doc") select x).First();

            AtomLink link = campaign.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.WorksheetRel, null);
            WorksheetQuery query2 = new WorksheetQuery(link.HRef.ToString());
            WorksheetFeed feed2 = myService.Query(query2);

            var campaignSheet = feed2.Entries.ElementAt(1); //First();   //0,2,3,4 here works

            try
            {
                AtomLink cellFeedLink = campaignSheet.Links.FindService(GDataSpreadsheetsNameTable.CellRel, null);
                CellQuery query3 = new CellQuery(cellFeedLink.HRef.ToString());
                CellFeed feed3 = myService.Query(query3);    **//Exception HERE**
```

Comment: Do you have Fiddler? If so, can you post the raw code that Fiddler is receiving in the response? Also in the one document that throws the error, does it contain any kind of extended characters, like foreign characters or anything?

Comment: I installed Fiddler, then the request worked one time :) After that when I was trying to debug I got the exceptions again. Will try look for that response

Answer (score 1):

I had same exception and in my case it was cause by our proxy server. I had possibility to use different proxy server and the same code worked fine. If you are behind a proxy server, you can try to specify proxy server in your SpreadsheetsService ( service.SpreadsheetsService.Proxy).